# Add option to select with data attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning of how to use jQuery but I stumbled with a block and can't get through it. How to append an `option` to a `select` with `data-*` attribute? Currently I'm appending option through this code below:

```
$('<option>').val(object.val).text(object.object.text).appendTo('#includedItems');
```

Is there a way to also add `data-*` to the options?

Comment: Use `.attr('data-something','somevalue')` to add data-* attribute. That's said, depending your use case, you could instead use the data object `.data('something','somevalue')` which won't update the DOM attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `attr()` or `data()` call to the chain:

use `attr()` if you want to have an actual `data-*` attribute:

```
$('<option>').val(object.val).text(object.object.text).attr('data-x', 'y').appendTo('#includedItems');
                                                       ^ call attr()
```

Use `data()` to use jQuery's internal data storage system (doesn't use an attribute)

```
$('<option>').val(object.val).text(object.object.text).data('x', 'y').appendTo('#includedItems');
                                                       ^ call data()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**,

```
$('<option>').attr('data-name','abcd');
```

Or **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
$('<option>').data('name','abcd');
```

---

```
$('<option>').val(object.val).attr('data-name','abcd').text(object.object.text).appendTo('#includedItems');
```

---

**Note:** `.data()` stores data in DOM object, NOT as Html attribute while `.attr()` does.

Comment: That's not the way to set attribute using jQuery `attr()` method

Comment: `.attr('data-name="abcd"');` will only try and read an attribute! You forgot the comma. (Who upvoted this???)

Comment: Sorry, copy pasted from my fiddle..I was trying things out..Updated my answer! Thanks for the find.

Comment: Your second option will likely store the value in the object's `data` and not as a `data-` attribute. Again, Who keeps upvoting this??? :)

Comment: It is also not doing anything with the result as it stands. Please complete your answer to match the question (and earn those upvotes) :)

Comment: Hooray... Got there in the end :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @TrueBlueAussie purposely didn't do it, so that the code would be more visible and not vanish under scrollable area.

Comment: Then you should have only shown the `attr()` part (as others did) and not complete lines that do nothing (including semi-colons) :) I will delete some of my comments shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 $('<option data-smdata="value"></option>').val(object.val).text(object.object.text).appendTo('#includedItems');
```

Comment: I *would* have upvoted you for getting in first, but I don't think adding HTML attributes in strings is generally a good idea (i.e. keep the `$('<..>')` part to a minimum where possible). *Note: This is purely from a maintenance perspective*. Cheers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: indeed. solution provided by shaunakde is better and feasible than mine. cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#dropdownId').append($('<option/>', {
     value: value,
     text: displayText,
     selected: isSelected ? true : false,
     'data-description': descriptionText
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr("data-lala",val)` to create an attribute on an element, or `.data("lala",val)` if you dont mind if that information stays hidden in the DOM (an inspect may not show the right value).